Design in Reactjs with TailwindCSS
I have a design to make. How can i make this type of design in reactjs with tailwindcss.
There are 2 tabs one is restake and other one is dashboard, and when I click on restake it goes up and dashboard goes down, and vice versa
The main problem here arises is how can I make the slant border of Restake and dashboard and should have a border color too.
i tried using this
<span className=`tab px-5 py-2 flex items-center cursor-pointer bg-[#0F162A] rounded-tr-2xl relative`>Restake</span>
}

.tab {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1a202c; /* Tailwind's gray-800 */
  color: #718096; /* Tailwind's gray-400 */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 50px) 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s; /* Smooth transition
}

But still it is not the same as it shows in the image and the border is also not curvy.



To create a design similar to the one shown in the images using React and Tailwind CSS, we'll need to create a custom component that handles the tab switching and styling. Here's a solution that closely mimics the design:
const TabSwitch = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('ReStake');

  const tabStyle = (tabName) => `
    relative px-6 py-3 text-lg font-semibold cursor-pointer transition-all duration-300
    ${activeTab === tabName ? 'text-white' : 'text-gray-400'}
  `;

  const tabBgStyle = (tabName) => `
    absolute inset-0 bg-blue-600 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out
    ${activeTab === tabName ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}
  `;

  const slantedEdge = `
    absolute top-0 bottom-0 w-6 bg-blue-600
    transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out
  `;

  return (
    <div className="flex bg-gray-900 rounded-t-lg overflow-hidden">
      <div className={`relative ${tabStyle('ReStake')}`} onClick={() => setActiveTab('ReStake')}>
        <div className={tabBgStyle('ReStake')}></div>
        <div className={`${slantedEdge} -right-3 skew-x-[20deg] origin-top-right ${activeTab === 'ReStake' ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}`}></div>
        <span className="relative z-10">ReStake</span>
      </div>
      <div className={`relative ${tabStyle('Dashboard')}`} onClick={() => setActiveTab('Dashboard')}>
        <div className={tabBgStyle('Dashboard')}></div>
        <div className={`${slantedEdge} -left-3 -skew-x-[20deg] origin-top-left ${activeTab === 'Dashboard' ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}`}></div>
        <span className="relative z-10">Dashboard</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TabSwitch;

This is the closest I've got.

it doesnt make the border slant,
